# identifying unexpected gl context loss in android

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, sdl, egl

when an android app is in the background the android os can clear its resources if its low on memory.

in my case its the `glcontext` and gl resources that are getting lost and crash the app.

in order to not restart the app entirely i would like to identify that this event had happened and recreate `Open GL` related resources.

i couldnt reproduce it / force this to happen.

**my questions are:**

does checking if `eglGetCurrentContext() == EGL_NO_CONTEXT` is enough to know that the context was lost? or there is an other way of knowing it?

is there any way to  reproduce this issue?

**specs**

the app logic is in c++ using `SDL2` framework.

the gl contexts get created by `SDL_GL_CreateContext(window)`.

i can make jani calls to java if needed.

Answer (score 1):

On your activity `onResume()` you will need to call `eglMakeCurrent()` to make your context the current context. If the context as been freed then that will set the EGL error state to `EGL_CONTEXT_LOST`.